# VS 2013 templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

All the msdn documents say I should have the following template options (see image below) when trying to create a new asp.net application but for some reason the only options I have are Empty, Web Forms, and Azure Mobile Service.

Does anyone know how I might go about restoring the missing options here as I need to create a new MVC application?

[image: Project Templates]

EDIT: Further clarification:

When following the steps carried out here ...
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio

... when I get to the above dialog I do not have any mention at all of both web API and MVC.

Comment: Could it be that you are using Visual Studio Express or something like that?

Comment: 2013 Ultimate with update 2 ... no its not likely that its an express problem since according to the msdn the free Express edition of VS2013 also has this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally cracked it ...

For some reason the web developer tools were not installed as part of my installation (likely due to the repair that happened last week).

So if anyone else gets this the fix is as follows:

Go to control panel  > programs and features 
Find "Visual Studio Ultimate 2013" entry.
Right click > change.
Click on "modify"
Tick the box labelled "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" and click to continue.

After running through the setup process everything should now be in place !
Wierd ... these options were in their correct place but apparently not after the repair !

Answer (score 0):

Please ..`Select WebForms`-> `Press Below Check for MVC` (This optional u can leave it for now )-> `Then you wil have an option for`

- MVC Application
- WEB API application
- ASP.NET WEB Application and so on!!

If no

reinstall or run some update for VS2013 ... its corrupted installation i guess or

clear APP-DATA ,TEMP AND MYDOCUEMNTS for VS related stuff...if u have massed it while working other settings...

Cheers!

Comment: the checkboxes in question do not exist for me ... that's why i'm asking this question.

Comment: reinstall or run some update ... its corrupted installation i guess or

Comment: well funnily enough i had serious problems with it the other day, it would load existing projects or even create any new project at all, in fact getting it to load without throwing loads of errors was an issue so whilst i was off my line manager did a repair. So it recently had a repair but I just went to add remove and told it to "modify" the install and it looks like im missing the web dev tools option being ticked in the installer. Running it through now.

Comment: Yes ... that could be the solution ..yes to `repair` using the DVD or a mounted USB iSO :)

Comment: I didn't need the iso, just had to "add features" to the existing install ... looking good now ! thanks for the help